# https version of my site added in Webmaster Tools - now statistics incorrect

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, https

I have 'upgraded' my site to SSL two weeks ago, and following the instructions given by Google, added the https:// version of the domain (which uses .htaccess to automatically redirect to the https://www.... version now) *as an extra entry* ('property') in Webmaster Tools ... but now, the statistics for the https:// version start only 2 weeks ago, while the ones for the http:// version end by then...

As a consequence, developments of certain things like Google Index status etc. are only partially displayed for each version - so if I focus on the SSL version from now on, I will 'lose' all those years of comparable data collected in Webmaster Tools.

Isn't there any way to 'combine' the data from both versions like Google Analytics seems to be able to (but which doesn't display half of the information Webmaster Tools can give me)?

Comment: Please note that google has begun to index https first before http wherever possible. More info http://searchengineland.com/google-to-begin-to-index-https-pages-first-before-http-pages-when-possible-238811
This doesn't solve your problem but maybe Google will begin combining http and https results in Search Console soon.

Comment: It's take some time to migrate, Google does not gives you statistics when URL are redirected from one site to another. Once your https version is indexed well, then you will see stats on GWT.  As far I know, Google also does not allowed to use change of tools from GWT, also Google start showing https version when possible, read out above link mention by garth. So I think, Google is smart enough about http and https version. Just make sure your sitemap, and canonical link point to https version, and gives some time to Google, they will surely do it's work automatically.

Comment: And here is Google's press release about their attitude toward https going forward. A very important read, and one that should dictate how you proceed with the setup of your SSL.  Note that they warn against blocking https using robot.txt and recommend that you setup every site to allow https access https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will simply take time to clear up. You are in a sense, shutting down one site and starting up another. This is why stats for one have ended and the other only show two weeks. Same with indexing and anything else.

HTTP versus HTTPS are two different sites as far as Google is concerned. Not sure why - it does not make sense to me, but I rather suspect it is an ounce of precaution and it is technically correct though traditionally they are often the same site.

You will see a fluctuation in search performance as well. If no-one told you there would be a disruption, then I am sorry for that - because it is always the case. In fact, it can be a rather large one. Almost like starting over but not quite.

So patience is what is needed. There is nothing to fix. It will all work out. It is just part of the price you pay when making this kind of a change.